# Prove that orthonormalsystem is an orthonormalbasis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series, lebesgue-integral

We have an orthonormalsystem in $L^2(0, 2\pi)$: $\{e^{ikx} : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
Now I want to show that it's also an orthonormalbasis.

I thought the easiest way to do that would be to show that for every $v \in L^2(0, 2\pi)$ with $(v,\phi_k) = 0, \phi_k(x) = e^{ikx}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $v(x) = 0$ for all $x$. But I'm stuck showing that if $\int_0^{2\pi} v(x)e^{ikx} dx = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $v=0$.

How do I proceed? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you know, for example, that the polynomials are dense in $L^{2}$ ? Also, do you know any complex analysis?

Comment: Yes, I know that and a little bit. I still want to know why if $\int_0^{2\pi} v(x)e^{ikx} dx = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $v=0$.

Comment: If you know some complex analysis, then you can show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}v(x)e^{ikx}dx=0$ for all $k$ forces $\int_{0}^{2\pi}v(x)e^{ikx}dx=0$ for all complex $k$, which allows you to take derivatives with respect to $k$ and show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}v(x)x^{n}dx=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know enough Fourier Analysis to know $x^{n}$ can be written as a Fourier series, then you can also conclude that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}v(x)x^{n}dx=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.

Comment: Mind to elaborate?

Comment: Which approach?

Comment: The first one with complex analysis.

Comment: Okay, I've posted that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a duplicate... A *trigonometric polynomial* is a linear combination of those exponentials. One of the theorems in the book, if not one of the definitions, shows that you only need to show that the trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. The notation $||.||_2$ will refer to that space:

Say $f\in L^2$ and $\epsilon>0$. Somewhere else in the book it shows that there is a function $g\in C([-\pi,\pi])$ with $||f-g||_2<\epsilon$. It's easy to modify $g$ to obtain a $2\pi$-periodic continuous function $h$ with $||g-h||_2<\epsilon$. Now Weierstrass says there is a trigonometric polynomial $P$ with $|h(t)-P(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $t$, hence $||h-P||_2\le\sqrt{2\pi}\epsilon$. Put it all together and the triangle inequality shows that $$||f-P||_2\le(1+1+\sqrt{2\pi})\epsilon.$$

Comment: Is there no way to prove it via the definition of an orthonormalbasis?

Comment: The definitions are not the same in every book - what definition do you have in mind? If _I_ were giving the definition of "orthonormal basis" the definition would be "orthonormal set such that the linear combinations are dense". Regardless, it's a theorem that that's equivalent to whatever your definition is. And it _must_ be a theorem right there in the book...

Comment: I have a bunch of pairwise equivalent properties for a orthonormalbasis. "Linear combinations are dense" is one of them. Another one is what I mentioned in my post, and a third one is that you can write each element as an infinite linear combination (fourier series).

Comment: Well then what's the problem? I sketched a proof that the linear combinations are dense, so you're done. Linear combinations dense plus the theorem prove what you say you wanted. (If you don't want to use the theorem learn the _proof_ of the theorem! Linear combinations dense plus the proof of the theorem also give what you say you want...) Theorems are there to be used.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to prove that if for every $k \in \mathbb{Z} \int_0^{2\pi} v(x)e^{ikx} dx = 0$ then $v = 0$.

Comment: I understand what you wanted to prove! I've explained how to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx$ is $0$ for $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$. Define a function
$$
               F(\lambda)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi i\lambda}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx.
$$
This function has removable singularities at $\lambda=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots$ because the integral vanishes for such $\lambda$. So $F$ extends to an entire function of $\lambda$. We show that $F$ must be identically $0$ by first showing that $F$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, applying Liouville's Theorem to conclude that $F$ is a constant, and then taking a limit to show the constant is $0$.

Let $C_{N}$ be the positively oriented simple closed contour which is the boundary of the square centered at $0$ of width $2N+1$. I'll leave it to you to work out the details of how there is a constant $M$ independent of $N > 0$ such that
$$
      \left|\frac{e^{-i\lambda x}}{e^{-2\pi i\lambda}-1}\right| \le M,
            \;\;\; 0 \le x \le 2\pi,\;\; \lambda \in C_{N}.
$$
Then, for any $\lambda' \in \mathbb{C}$, there is $N'$ such that $\lambda'$ is inside $C_N$ for $N\ge N'$, and
$$
       F(\lambda') = \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{C_{N}}\frac{F(\lambda)}{\lambda-\lambda'}d\lambda,\;\;\; N \ge N'.
$$
Using the uniform boundedness of $F$ on all $C_{N}$, you can take a limit of the above as $N\rightarrow \infty$ in order to show that $F$ is uniformly bounded everywhere in the plane. Hence $F$ is a constant by Liouville's theorem. Therefore, there is a constant $C$ such that
$$
            \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx = C(1-e^{-2\pi i\lambda}),
                 \;\;\; \lambda \in \mathbb{C}.
$$
Set $\lambda = -ir$ and let $r\rightarrow\infty$ to determine the constant:
$$
               \lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-rx}dx = \lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}C(1-e^{-2\pi rx}) \\
                       0 = C.
$$
Therefore,
$$
                        \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx = 0,\;\;\;\lambda\in\mathbb{C}.
$$
That means you can take all orders of derivatives at $\lambda=0$ and also get $0$:
$$
                  0= \left.\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx\right|_{\lambda = 0} = (-i)^{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)x^{n}dx.
$$
So $f$ must be $0$ a.e. because the polynomials are dense in $L^{2}$.